# Django: Iterate over QuerySet by content of a field

Tags: python, django

I need to iterate over a set of model objects, by the content of two fields. Code may make more sense.

This is my model definition:

```
class Widget(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(WidgetGroup)
    style = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
```

I want to act on widgets of the same group and style, so I use the following code. It works, but it doesn't seem 'neat' enough for typical python and Django. Is there a better way to do it?

```
widgets = Widget.objects.all()
for group in WidgetGroup.objects.all():
    group_widgets = widgets.filter(group=group)
    for style in set(group_widgets.values_list('style', flat=True)):
        group_style_widgets = group_widgets.filter(style=style)
        # Do something with group_style_widgets
```

Edit: it *is* important to me that I iterate by group first, and then style. Think intended output like this Markdown:

```
# Group1
## Style1
## Style2
# Group2
## Style2
## Style3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
for group in WidgetGroup.objects.prefetch_related('widget_set').all():
    for group_style_widgets in group.widget_set.all():
        # Do something with group_style_widgets
```

Or if you want to specifically use the styles:

```
styles = Widget.objects.all().values_list('style', flat=True).distinct()
for group in WidgetGroup.objects.prefetch_related('widget_set').all():
    for style in styles:
        group_style_widgets = group.widget_set.filter(style=style)
        # Do something with group_style_widgets
```